# How can I know from Chef Management if my "chef-client" failed during update?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a question about CHEF. I deployed several nodes on my Chef Server (using Chef Hosting) with different configuration but with one common cookbook. I have "cron" on my nodes which run 'chef-client' each day.

My question is: Is it possible to know from Chef Management, if the 'chef-client' failed on my nodes WITHOUT the need to connect to each node to check manually ?

Because currently when I force a fail on a node, I don't see any change on my Chef Management. I mean, I can't see the difference between a node where the 'chef-client' failed  and a node where the 'chef-client' pass with success...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [knife status](https://docs.chef.io/knife_status.html) command that will report a brief summary of the nodes on a Chef server, including the time of the most recent successful chef-client run

I can recommend the [knife lastrun](https://github.com/jgoulah/knife-lastrun) plugin which can be used to add additional metadata to the chef node indicating the success/failure and error message of the last chef run.

Finally the commercial analytics plugin reports the status of each chef client.

- https://www.chef.io/blog/2015/07/07/chef-analytics-1-1-4-release/